# 関数内部でglobal宣言よりもnonlocal宣言が優先されるのはなぜですか？

Tags: python, python3

```
def scope_test():
    def do_local():
        spam="local spam"
    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal spam
        spam="non-local spam"
    def do_global():
        global spam
        spam="global spam"
    spam="test spam"
    do_local()
    print("After local assignment:", spam)
    do_nonlocal()
    print("After nonlocal assignment:", spam)
    do_global()
    print("After global assignment:", spam)

scope_test()
print("In global assignment:", spam)
```

出力はこうなる：

```
After local assignment: test spam
After nonlocal assignment: non-local spam
After global assignment: non-local spam
In global scope: global spam
```

らしいのですが、"After global assignment: non-local spam"となる理由がわかりません。なぜ、do_global(): global spamの次にあるのに、"global spam"ではなく"non-local spam"となるか、初心者でもわかるように、超簡単にご説明いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 5):

そのプログラムでは合計３つの`spam`変数が登場しますが、区別できるようにコメントをつけるとこうなります。

```
def scope_test():
    def do_local():
        spam="local spam" # spam1
    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal spam # spam2
        spam="non-local spam"
    def do_global():
        global spam # spam3
        spam="global spam"
    spam="test spam" # spam2
    do_local()
    print("After local assignment:", spam) # spam2
    do_nonlocal()
    print("After nonlocal assignment:", spam) # spam2
    do_global()
    print("After global assignment:", spam) # spam2

scope_test()
print("In global assignment:", spam) # spam3
```

`do_local`は当然ローカル変数`spam`を宣言して代入しているだけなので、`scope_test`で宣言された変数`spam`(spam2)には影響しません。

`do_non_local`は`nonlocal spam`により、グローバルスコープを除く外側のスコープに存在する一番階層が近い変数`spam`(この場合spam2)を使いますよ、と宣言することになります。よって`do_non_local`を実行後はspam2の値は`"non-local spam"`になります。

(グローバルスコープとは一番外側のスコープです)

最後に`do_global`は`global spam`によりグローバルスコープの変数`spam`を使いますよ、と宣言します。コードにはグローバル変数`spam`の宣言がありませんが、`do_global`内で`spam="global spam"`を実行した時点で、グローバル変数`spam`(spam3)が作られます。

結局、`do_global`はspam2に影響しないので、`"non-local spam"`が出力されるということになります。

Comment: 「変数名変えたらそうなるのは当たり前では」と思われるだけで説明になってないのではないでしょうか。理屈がわかってる人にであればこれで意図も伝わるかもしれませんが。

Comment: @suzukis スコープの説明は面倒だったので、どの`spam`がどの`spam`と対応しているのかを示せば理解の助けになるというつもりでした。しかしご指摘頂いたとおり分かりにくかったので、説明を追加していきます。

Answer (score 1):

超簡単かどうかはわからないですが、単純に言えば

```
    print("After global assignment:", spam)
```

これがscope_test()関数のスコープ内で実行されているのでglobalではなくnonlocalなspamを出力します。ヒントとして、もしこの行のインデントを取り払えば、それはもはやscope_test()の(nonlocalな)スコープではなくglobalなスコープでの実行になるので"global spam"と出力されるでしょう。

do_global()というのは確かにグローバルスコープのspamを代入操作によって更新しますが、だからといって後続の

```
    print("After global assignment:", spam)
```

がグローバルスコープで実行されるわけではないということです。つまり値の更新と評価に関係がないわけです。実際この文はnonlocalなスコープで呼び出されていますね。

Answer (score 1):

do_localは問題の核心ではないので省いて説明します。

```
def scope_test():    
    spam = "local spam"
    def do_nonlocal():     
        nonlocal spam
        spam = "non_local spam"        
    def do_global():
        global spam
        spam = "global spam"

    do_nonlocal()
    print("After non_local assignment:", spam)
    do_global()
    print("After global assignment:", spam)
scope_test()
print("In global assignment:", spam)
```

**結果1**

```
After non_local assignment: non_local spam
After global assignment: non_local spam
In global assignment: global spam
```

上のコードは、このコードと等価です。

```
spam = "global spam"
def scope_test():    

    def do_nonlocal():     
        nonlocal spam
        spam = "non_local spam"        
    def do_global():
        pass
    spam = "test spam"
    do_nonlocal()
    print("After non_local assignment:", spam)
    do_global()
    print("After global assignment:", spam)
scope_test()
print("In global assignment:", spam)
```

**結果2**

```
After non_local assignment: non_local spam
After global assignment: non_local spam
In global assignment: global spam
```

global宣言は、グローバルスコープ=トップレベルで変数を定義したということを意味します。

nonlocal宣言すらパスすると、こうなります。

```
spam = "global spam"
def scope_test():    
    def do_nonlocal():     
        pass     
    def do_global():
        pass
    do_nonlocal()
    print("After non_local assignment:", spam)
    do_global()
    print("After global assignment:", spam)
scope_test()
print("In global assignment:", spam)
```

**結果3**

```
After non_local assignment: global spam
After global assignment: global spam
In global assignment: global spam
```

nonlocal宣言を使うための条件
**・ネストされた関数内で宣言することが必要。(ここではdo_nonlocal配下)

・宣言前にスコープ外であらかじめ変数を定義しておくことが必要。(scope_test配下)

・global宣言を受けた変数ではない。**

nonlocal宣言を書けば,その変数は、ネスト関数配下のローカル変数とは扱われなくなります。

```
def do_global():
    global spam
    spam = "global spam"
```

**一番の疑問**
で、do_nonlocal()を呼び出した後で、do_global()を呼び出しているのに、なぜ、
spamは、上書きされないのでしょうか？
このspamは、結果2と同じ定め方をされているので、do_global()では、上書きできないのだと考えます。

Answer (score 0):

簡単に言えば、関数内にグローバルと同名の変数がある場合のみ
それぞれの変数は別の変数に変身します。
つまりノンローカルが優先されているのではなく
グローバルがその変数に関与していないだけです。
ためしに

```
do_local()
print("After local assignment:", spam)
do_nonlocal()
print("After nonlocal assignment:", spam)
```

を消して実行してみてください。意味がわかると思います。